# Время выполнения SQL запросов

Tags: php, sql

Пытаюсь встроить функцию на сайт, контролирующую sql-запросы и время на них потраченное. Нарыл в инете интересное решение. Работать работает, но выдаёт в результат всё время 1 sql-запрос. Чувствую, что собака зарыта в строчке **$sql_time+=do_query("SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE");** но ничего не получается. Подскажите, пожалуйста в чём дело?

```
//Засекаем время старта
    $mtime = microtime();
    $mtime = explode(" ",$mtime);
    $mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
    $tstart = $mtime;

//Коннектимся к базе:
    include 'connect.php';

//Объявляем переменные
    $result=0;
    $qnum=0;

//Объявляем нашу функцию
    function do_query($query){
    global $result;
    global $qnum;
        $qnum++;

        $mtime = microtime(); 
        $mtime = explode(" ",$mtime); 
        $mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0]; 
        $tstart = $mtime;

        $result = MYSQL_QUERY($query);

        $mtime = microtime(); 
        $mtime = explode(" ",$mtime); 
        $mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0]; 
        $tend = $mtime; 
        $tpassed = ($tend - $tstart); 
        return($tpassed);
    }

//Далее тело скрипта
    $sql_time+=do_query("SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE");
//Обрабатываем данные
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        print($row['Text']);
    }

//Засекаем время окончания
    $mtime = microtime(); 
    $mtime = explode(" ",$mtime); 
    $mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0]; 
    $tend = $mtime; 
    $total = ($tend - $tstart);

//Выдаем время:
    printf("SQL запросов: $qnum, время mysql: %f,
      всего затрачено: %f секунд !", $sql_time, $total);

//Вычисляем процент времени:
    $sqlpercent = ($sql_time*100)/$total;
    print('Процент времени на MySQL: '. round($sqlpercent, 2) . '%');
```

Answer (score 3):

Что-то намудрили. Засекли время, выполнили запрос, посмотрели время снова. Добавили счётчик запросов.

```
// инициализировали счётчики
$sqlCount = 0;
$sqlTime = 0;

// для каждого SQL запроса:
$timeStart = microtime( TRUE);
// выполняем SQL запрос
...
$sqlTime += microtime( TRUE) - $timeStart;
$sqlCount++;

// Итоги
printf( '%d запросов за %01.2f секунд.', $sqlCount, $sqlTime);
```

Answer (score -1):

Вообще задача до смеха легкая. Но наговнокодили вы жестоко, нужно обязательно реабилитироваться! Ниже класс, который нужно объявлять в начале старта приложения, и в конце аппликации выводить информацию о запросах. Для подключения к mySQL заюзал PDO. Также замечу, что код на работоспособность не проверял, но по сути он правильный. Сначала мы замеряем время подключения к БД, потом замеряем время запроса и время выборки.

```
<?php

class GetSQLTime extends PDO {
    private $db, $sqlNum, $allTime = 0;

    /**
     * connect
     */
    function __construct () {
        $start = getmicrotime();
        //
        parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $password, $driver);
        //
        $stop = getmicrotime();
        //
        $this->allTime += $stop-$start;
    }

    /**
     * query
     */
    function query($qu) {
        $this->sqlNum++;
        //
        $start = getmicrotime();
        //
        $return = $db->query($qu);
        //
        $stop = getmicrotime();
        //
        $this->allTime += $stop-$start;
        //
        return $return;
    }

    function fetch($qu) {
        //
        $start = getmicrotime();
        //
        $return = $db->fetch($qu);
        //
        $stop = getmicrotime();
        //
        $this->allTime += $stop-$start;
        //
        return $return;
    }

    /**
     * stop app
     */
    function end() {
        return "sql запросов: ".$this->sqlNum."; Затрачено времени: ".$this->allTime.".\n<br>";
    }

    /**
     * getmicrotime
     */
    function getmicrotime() { 
        list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime()); 
        return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec); 
    } 
}

$time = new GetSQLTime();

$query = $time->query('1234');

while($fetch = $query->fetch()) {
    var_dump($fetch);
}

$time->end();
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но проблема в том, что я в ООП PDO разбираюсь не лучше, чем в балете, а в балете я ничего не понимаю. В коде я ничего не понял. 95% написанного я вижу в первый раз (это тёмный лес).
"на работоспособность не проверял, но по сути он правильный". Это конечно здорого. Но и мой код "по сути он правильный", и не только по сути, но и по работоспасобности. Проблема в том, что я встроить не могу его в свой скрипт.

Comment: Да тут понимать особо ничего и не нужно :) Нужно только попробовать! Это далеко не ООП, это просто класс. Класс, который содержит функции. Мы просто объявляем класс, а потом просто вызываем функции, которые содержит этот класс. Попробуйте!

Comment: почему никто не использует `microtime( TRUE)`, все парсят возвращаемые строки? =) Дурная наследственность : )

Comment: @sergiks Я вообще не вникал в код, а только составил удобный инструмент :-)

Answer (score -1):

Самый простой способ:

```
$start_time = microtime(true);
$result = mysql_query($sql_string, $connection);
$query_time = (microtime(true)-$start_time)/1000;
echo "Запрос выполнялся $query_time миллисекунд";
```

Как-то так.